# LINQ to SQL - Using 'Select new' and navigation / child tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I've constructed a LINQ to SQL statement that pulls back records via an Entity Framework. The child tables are populated automatically (I think this is called navigation?)  Now I have a CLOB field present which means I have to construct the statement to send to a list first, then make distinct:

```
 var getResult = (from u in _dbRo.ParentTable
     join t in _dbRo.ChildTAble on u.ID equals t.PARENT_ID
     where 
          u.CURRENT == "Y" 

     select u).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
```

The problem I have with this, although it works is it's very inefficient.  Because a DISTINCT is not wrapped around the generated SQL (I've got a monitoring tool which confirms this) I end up with around 80 records, but in reality there is only 7 when the duplications on the fields I'm after are taken out.

I've tried using the below 'select new':

```
select (MainTable) new MainTableInheritance
{
    Examplefield = u.Examplefield,
    ChildTableRecords= u.ChildTableRecords
}
```

And it's here that I start having problems.  I just can't get the child tables to populate.  ChildTableRecords is an entity set, and despite trying a few methods I've not had any luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: *Don't* call `ToList` before Distinct. Instead of performing a DISTINCT query, you ask for all rows from the database with `ToList()` and then perform a LINQ-to-Objects `Distinct()` on the resulting objects. This isn't a LINQ to SQL issue, it's the code that actually asks for all objects. Try  `select u).Distinct().ToList();` instead

Comment: Hiya, I have to use ToList().Distinct().ToLIst() because of the CLOB field.  using .Distinct.ToList() just throws an error because you can't do this directly with a CLOB.  So the route I'm trying to do now is 'select new' and select all the fields accept the field which is CLOB, but thats when I have problems getting my child tables populated.

Comment: First,  what CLOB field? Second,  you couldn't use a varchar(max)  in a SQL DISTINCT either.  Fix your query to return only the necessary fields.  Or change it altogether - Why do you want join tables instead of specifying a relationship between them in the mappings?

Comment: Hi again.  The example code I've included is just that.  The real version that I'm using has about 15/20 fields of which 1 is a CLOB datatype (Character Large Object) in an Oracle database.  In terms of fixing the SQL, that is what I've been attempting by using 'select new' to select everything except this CLOB field.  My experience in this area is limited, but I'm pretty sure the solution resides within the 'select new'. I can run the query in my select new approach, but the child tables don't auto populate like they do if I just do 'select u' as shown in my example.

Comment: The problem is the lack of relations, not the JOIN or `DISTINCT`. There would be **no reason** to use a join if `ParentEntity` (not table, you are dealing with *entities* not tables), had a `Children` collection. You could simply write eg `_dbRo.Orders.Where(u=>u.Current=="Y");` and then simply iterate over the `LineItems` collection. Or write `_dbRo.Orders.Where(u=>u.Current=="Y").Include("LineItem");` to load all children at once and avoid multiple round-trips

Comment: Hi, I've spent some time experimenting and I think the problem resides with  the object that uses inheritance.  In Devart's LinqConnect there is a .ExecuteQuery<Entity>(qrySQL) approach you can do.  When I use the object that inherits all the fields from the parent entity/table it fails (despite having setup navigation).  The messages that have popped up point to these relationships.  If I use the actual main parent entity that I'm trying to inherit it works fine.  It's this that I think has muddied the water as so to speak and agree the example you posted would work.